# What does AllowLocation="true" do in System.Web section of Web.Config?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, configuration, .net-2.0

We have a .NET 2.0 application which we normally run on IIS6, and used to run fine on IIS7, but recently after installing SP1 for Vista  IIS7 seems to be choking on a line in the Web.Config file:

```
<system.web AllowLocation="true">
```

Is it safe to remove the AllowLocation attribute? What does this attribute do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:

> When set to false, the AllowLocation property indicates that the section is accessed by native-code readers. Therefore, the use of the location attribute is not allowed, because the native-code readers do not support the concept of location.

The default value is true, so you should be able to remove it with no effect on your application.

Comment: There was no effect on the application in either IIS6 or IIS7.

Answer (score 0):

Having this set to true should enable any `<location>` sections in your web.config, so you should be fine to remove it if there's none in there.

Comment: Interestingly, we do have <location> sections in our Web.Config file, so  I tried removing the tag and experienced no effect what-so-ever on the behavior of the application.